# mod rewrite clear home url for tomcat + apache

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a struts app running on Apache front end of Tomcat via mod-jk.

I am trying to use mod-rewrite to clean some of the action urls generate by struts.

**Example:** rewrite (works fine)

`http://www.demo.com/context/user.do?action=aboutus` to `http://www.demo.com/context/aboutus` using
`RewriteRule ^/msn/aboutus$ /msn/user.do?action=aboutus [PT,L]`.

**Problem:** I'd like to rewrite the `http://www.demo.com/context/user.do?action=home` to  `http://www.demo.com` (homepage)

I tried this
`RewriteRule ^/$ /context/userdo?action=home [PT,L]` which does not work.

**FYI**

All the css,js and links are on relative path.

DirectoryIndex is on index.html (Does it change mod-rewrite behaviour?)

Tomcat Version 5.5, Application deploy via exploding the WAR file in `public_html/context/` folder (multiple deployment)

URLrewrite filter does not help to remove the context name according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556407/urlrewritefilter-how-to-remove-the-context-folder-name).

**Logs**

I tired to have a look at the log file (snapshots) which doesn't give any warning error messages.

```
(3) applying pattern '^/$' to uri '/context/jsps/images/abc.png'
(3) applying pattern '^/abc/aboutus$' to uri '/abc/jsps/images/abc.png'   
(3) applying pattern '^/abc/home$' to uri
'/abc/jsps/images/abc.png'
```

Anyone can give me some ideas what went wrong? and how can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think in your case of rewriting `^/$` it is mod_jk that is taking precedence over mod_rewrite rules since using mod_jk you are forwarding **everything** eg: `/*` to Tomcat from Apache. I will suggest using [URLRewriteFilter](http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/) within your Tomcat app to achieve these URL rewrites properly.

Comment: installed that. It seems all my url rewrites are based from the context. `/abc/rewrite` for example. How can I remove the context name?

Comment: I'm so sorry to respond so late. To remove the context simply use `<urlrewrite use-context="false">` as root tag in `urlrewrite.xml`